# File Symbolic link broken as shown in Desktop icon

Tags: files

I have a text file (ubuntu.txt) stored in a NTFS partition - `/media/des/WD`

```
# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 des  des    33 Sep 26 06:51 Link to ubuntu.txt -> /media/des/WD/Linux OS/ubuntu.txt``
```

I created a link by right clicking on the text file --> Make link. Then I drag the newly created link file to my Desktop. It has been working until I rebooted my Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, the link is broken. (As seen in the icon with a padlock).

If I go inside the NTFS partition folder `/media/des/WD/Linux OS` I can see the link and double clicking it will open the file.

I am suspecting something to do with the mount point `/media/des/WD` that is causing it.

Comment: Is the NTFS partition automounted?

Comment: Yes the NTFS is auto mounted by Ubuntu under /media

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the broken link problem by manually mounting the mount point and make it persistent in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sdb5    /media/WESTERN       ntfs     auto
```

Upon reboot, the mount point `/media/WESTERN` will appear under devices.